# Docker stuck in created status after system reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running two docker containers with `docker-compose`. I've written the following yaml file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  initializer:
    image: my-container1
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/logs

  worker:
    image: my-container2
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/logs
    depends_on:
      - initializer
```

- When I run it directly with `docker-compose up -d`, the containers are up and perfectly running.
- When I reboot my device, only the initializer container is up. The worker is stuck with a created status.

Could it be an issue with the available memory of my device at boot (512MB) ?
How can I get logs or errors to fix that ?

When I run `docker stats` on my worker, it is only using a few memory:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME         CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O         BLOCK I/O   PIDS
48945397ec13   root_woker   0.17%     4.738MiB / 491.2MiB   0.96%     1.21kB / 898B   0B / 0B     4
```

---

**EDIT:** This might be an issue with docker or docker-compose.
If I create a linux service, the containers are correctly created and launched.

I've written this content to `/etc/systemd/system/docker-compose-app.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker compose Application Service
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/my-repository
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose up -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose down
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And enabled on system boot:

```
systemctl enable docker-compose-app
systemctl start docker-compose-app
```

Comment: please use "docker ps -a", get the containerID, run "docker logs <ContainerID>". Also have a look at the "./logs" directory (binding mount) to see logs.

Comment: are you able to do a docker compose logs?

Comment: docker logs returns nothing for the worker container. Logs directory is only providing logs for initializer.
Compose logs return `Attaching to root_worker_1 root_initializer_1`

Comment: Are you able to confirm there is no port conflict ?  especially for the worker one

Comment: The worker container is not using any port :/